# Package a timeseries of GeoTIFF rasters as a single NetCDF file

Tags: python, regex, gdal, netcdf, geotiff

I tried to use [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70458/convert-timeseries-stack-of-gtiff-raster-to-single-netcdf) for my Image stacks, but I doesn't go through data!!

I think the problem could be from the **pat** which use *regex* to extract year and month from file path.

All the data are in a folder called **data_sample** and here is the name of the files:

```
R20060111_075725___SIG0__ASAWS___M1VVD_TUW_SGRT15A00_AF075M_E060N054T6.tif
R20060114_080443___SIG0__ASAWS___M1VVD_TUW_SGRT15A00_AF075M_E060N054T6.tif
R20060117_081036___SIG0__ASAWS___M1VVD_TUW_SGRT15A00_AF075M_E060N054T6.tif
R20060118_073857___SIG0__ASAWS___M1VVD_TUW_SGRT15A00_AF075M_E060N054T6.tif
```

the output is:

```
dimensions:
    lon = 8000 ;
    lat = 8000 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (0 currently)
variables:
    float time(time) ;
        time:units = "days since 2006-01-11 00:00:00" ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
    float lon(lon) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
    float lat(lat) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
    int crs ;
        crs:long_name = "Lon/Lat Coords in WGS84" ;
        crs:grid_mapping_name = "latitude_longitude" ;
        crs:longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0. ;
        crs:semi_major_axis = 6378137. ;
        crs:inverse_flattening = 298.257223563 ;
    short tmn(time, lat, lon) ;
        tmn:_FillValue = -9999s ;
        tmn:units = "degC" ;
        tmn:scale_factor = 0.01 ;
        tmn:add_offset = 0. ;
        tmn:long_name = "minimum monthly temperature" ;
        tmn:standard_name = "air_temperature" ;
        tmn:grid_mapping = "crs" ;

// global attributes:
        :Conventions = "CF-1.6" ;
}
```

and here is the code which I edited (@rich-signell)

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import os
import gdal
import netCDF4
import re

ds = gdal.Open('/data_sample/R20060111_075725___SIG0__ASAWS___M1VVD_TUW_SGRT15A00_AF075M_E060N054T6.tif')

a = ds.ReadAsArray()
nlat, nlon = np.shape(a)

b = ds.GetGeoTransform()  # bbox, interval
lon = np.arange(nlon)*b[1]+b[0]
lat = np.arange(nlat)*b[5]+b[3]

basedate = dt.datetime(2006, 01, 11, 0, 0, 0)

# Create NetCDF file
nco = netCDF4.Dataset('time_series.nc', 'w', clobber=True)

chunk_lon = 16
chunk_lat = 16
chunk_time = 12

# Create dimensions, variables and attributes:
nco.createDimension('lon', nlon)
nco.createDimension('lat', nlat)
nco.createDimension('time', None)

timeo = nco.createVariable('time', 'f4', ('time',))
timeo.units = 'days since 2006-01-11 00:00:00'
timeo.standard_name = 'time'

lono = nco.createVariable('lon', 'f4', ('lon',))
lono.standard_name = 'longitude'

lato = nco.createVariable('lat', 'f4', ('lat',))
lato.standard_name = 'latitude'

# Create container variable for CRS: lon/lat WGS84 datum
crso = nco.createVariable('crs', 'i4')
crso.long_name = 'Lon/Lat Coords in WGS84'
crso.grid_mapping_name = 'latitude_longitude'
crso.longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0
crso.semi_major_axis = 6378137.0
crso.inverse_flattening = 298.257223563

# Create short integer variable for temperature data, with chunking
tmno = nco.createVariable('tmn', 'i2',  ('time', 'lat', 'lon'),
                          zlib=True, chunksizes=[chunk_time,
                                                 chunk_lat,
                                                 chunk_lon],
                          fill_value=-9999)
tmno.units = 'degC'
tmno.scale_factor = 0.01
tmno.add_offset = 0.00
tmno.long_name = 'minimum monthly temperature'
tmno.standard_name = 'air_temperature'
tmno.grid_mapping = 'crs'
tmno.set_auto_maskandscale(False)

nco.Conventions = 'CF-1.6'

# Write lon,lat
lono[:] = lon
lato[:] = lat

pat = re.compile('(\w{1})(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})_\d{6}')
itime = 0

# Step through data, writing time and data to NetCDF
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/data_sample/'):
    dirs.sort()
    files.sort()
    for f in files:
        if re.match(pat, f):
            # read the time values by parsing the filename
            year = int(f[4:8])
            mon = int(f[8:10])
            date = dt.datetime(year, mon, 1, 0, 0, 0)
            print(date)
            dtime = (date-basedate).total_seconds()/86400.
            timeo[itime] = dtime
            # min temp
            tmn_path = os.path.join(root, f)
            print(tmn_path)
            tmn = gdal.Open(tmn_path)
            a = tmn.ReadAsArray()  # data
            tmno[itime, :, :] = a
            itime = itime+1

nco.close()
```

Does someone know where could be a problem ?
Thank you

Comment: Do you know you can just access the capture groups by their IDs? `match = re.match(pat, f) // if match: // year = int(m.group(2)) // mon = int(m.group(3))`

Comment: @stribizhev No I don't know how to do it

Comment: Check [this code](http://ideone.com/oLggiv), I hope it helps.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for the code, but again my output is the same as before. what I did: `for f in files: // match=re.match(pat, f) // if match: // year = int(m.group(2)) // mon = int(m.group(3))`

Comment: If you use `match` as *MatchData* object, you need to use it later, not `m`.

Comment: @stribizhev yeah I used **match**, that was mistake in writing here

Comment: Then please provide your code demo on IDEONE. Perhaps, you just forget to assign new results to the existing variables or something. The regex extracts the data you need well. Try with `re.search` in case you have initial whitespace (or with `\s*` at the pattern start). Are you sure you are using a raw string literal (`r""`)? Try with that one, too.

Comment: @stribizhev [code](http://ideone.com/ucYJZj)

Comment: It is not working due to missing external modules. Please adjust it so that it could be used to repro your issue. I believe you will find the problem while amending the code that way.